# Replace JPA @Query with two queries?

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, hql

I have one legacy application that uses Spring JPA. THere's one method with @Query annotation. It needs to be replaced with two queries. What's the easiest approach ? THanks.

Comment: easiest will be to add another query in repository layer and call both the queries in service layer

Comment: Be aware about n+1 problem.